# getting node value of element from an array

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a function where different things happen to classed elements based on their contents.  For instance, if several elements have class name "name", and I want to highlight all the ones where the content (or nodevalue) is "Joe", can I create an if test while looping through the getElementsByClassName array?

Here is an example of a function that hasn't worked:

```
function hey()
{var h = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
 for(i=0; i<h.length; i++)
    {var thisOne = h[i];
    if (thisOne[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue="Joe"){thisOne.style.color="red"}
    else{thisOne.style.color="blue"}
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `thisOne[0]` should be `thisOne` and `nodeValue="Joe"` should be `nodeValue === "Joe"` (you seem to know that `=` is an assignment).

Comment: Yes, that did it.  Have to admit, I'm still getting a handle on =/==/===.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can test the text content of an element using the [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) method. This assumes the node has no other content than what is being tested, but it could be within a child element created by, say, a `span` tag. You may need to trim the result if a "name" container contains additional white space.

```js
function hey()
{var h = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
 for(i=0; i<h.length; i++)
    {var thisOne = h[i];
    if( thisOne.textContent.trim() == "Joe") {
        thisOne.style.color="red"
    }
    else {
        thisOne.style.color="blue"}
    }
}
hey();
```

```html
<p class="name">
  Joe
</p>
<p class="name">
  Felix
</p>

And another <span class="name"> Joe </span>
```